# Getting "XMLHttpRequest is not defined"

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Getting XMLHttpRequest is not defined, this is my first time trying this stuff. Using .open'GET' with an APi url.

```js
var weatherData;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

loadData();

function loadData() {
  request.open('GET', 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=15&difficulty=easy&type=boolean');
  request.onload = loadComplete;
  request.send();
}

function loadComplete(evt) {
  weatherData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  console.log(weatherData);

}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. You code seems fine and works for me.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a predefined object in browsers,for backend you need it to install its package

Comment: Please specify which environment you are trying. your code works fine on browser.

Comment: @Wendelin Really? Lucky... lol I keep getting that its not defined. Makes no sense

Comment: @zero_two I have to use it in VSCode for a game

Comment: then you must be using npm and you are making this with node.js. you can install package from npm. It will work like browser then.

this is the package -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest

Comment: @zero_two Talking about  npm install xmlhttprequest  ?? I did install that and still getting the error

Comment: ok did you import the library? you need to add 
`var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest; ` 
at the top of the file.

Comment: you can see the [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest#usage) section of that library.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add this snippet:

```
 var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```